# Simple Deform "Bend" Option Wont Work

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm trying to follow a CGGeek tutorial on making the earth. I can't follow along because right away the *Bend* modifier won't work.

Things I've tried:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> for rotation
- Changing the axis

[image]

Comment: did you subdivide the plane? you should subdivide it a few times....until it looks smooth. If this doesn't help, please provide blend file

Comment: @vklidu: oooops, yes he has 

Comment: Ok, please provide blend file so we can check it out

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to [this tut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4HNIbDn4K4)?

It didn't work for me too, but if I set Plane along X axis with Rotation applied <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> ...
it works for me.

[image]